# when they become old / when they would become old

Tags: sentence-construction

I am too confused to answer the question:

> Why was the boy making a wooden bowl?

Shall I write:

> The boy was making a wooden bowl so that he could give it to his parents **when they become old / when they would become old.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sorry, where did you take this example?

Answer (score 1):

Neither of the answers is idiomatic.

Native English speakers do not talk about people becoming old.

They will say things like **when they age, when they are old, in their old age, when they retire** and so on.

If you have to choose between the two options, prefer **when they become old** but be aware that it is not fluent English.

**When they would become old** is simply wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Not "would become old."

"Become old" is OK, though you might mean "became old." The choice of tense depends on when all of this takes place. If the boy is young George Washington, so his parents are now long since dead, you'd use *became*. But if the boy is alive today and his parents are still young, then it's *become*.

By the way, in answering that, I assumed that your purpose in asking was to understand which form to use after "so that he could." But now I'll add a different point: the phrase "become old" is unnatural. One might say, "when they **are** old," or "when they **were** old."

Comment: GOOD WAY OF EXPLAINING! THANKS!

Comment: You're welcome. Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem. See also [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 0):

There is such an example from the literature on ethical issues in societies:'On the other hand members of the society have prima facie claims to equal access to common resources, and the present aged can not be abandoned in order to benefit the present young when they will become old.' , *Extending the Human Life Span: Social Policy and Social Ethics*, 1977.

It's a special case of modal verb *will* in the Future time clause with a meaning of *'when it is true now that...'* with the Present tense markers. That is in compliance with the general rule of the grammar construction of the Future time clause.

At that, the sentence *'The boy was making a wooden bowl so that he could give it to his parents when they are old'*  seems to be somewhat not how it sounds.

Comment: very interesting. Do we know anything about that passage's author (s)? I wonder if they are native anglophones.

Comment: Disturbance is not sort of well grounded. Because an edited example has been provided. What about the US-UK editorial team of some well-known language works?